# rebuild Python project which imports own package run in Docker while in development

Tags: python, docker

I have a python project with file structure as below

```
- src
|- myproject
 |- main.py
- pyproject.toml
```

in the main.py, it references to its own package like this.

```py
from myproject.server import MyprojectServiceServicer
```

currently, I run the project using Docker with Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml below

```
# syntax = docker/dockerfile:1-labs
FROM python:3.11

WORKDIR /app
COPY --link ./pyproject.toml /app/pyproject.toml
COPY --link ./src /app/src

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -v /app
```

```
version: '3'
services:
  myproject:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    environment:
      - PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
      - PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    entrypoint: "python /app/src/generative_agents/main.py"
```

the problem is that the project is referencing own package built via `pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -v /app` and it has symbolic link to copied "src" directory and not the local files.
so whenever I make some changes to code and want to test it out, I have to rebuild the image and is slowing me down.

Is there any way to update project's package while referencing to local files? or only execute copying local files and build package when rebuilding?

I have a python project with file structure as below

```
- src
|- myproject
 |- main.py
- pyproject.toml
```

in the main.py, it references to its own package like this.

```py
from myproject.server import MyprojectServiceServicer
```

currently, I run the project using Docker with Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml below

```
# syntax = docker/dockerfile:1-labs
FROM python:3.11

WORKDIR /app
COPY --link ./pyproject.toml /app/pyproject.toml
COPY --link ./src /app/src

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -v /app
```

```
version: '3'
services:
  myproject:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    environment:
      - PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
      - PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    entrypoint: "python /app/src/generative_agents/main.py"
```

the problem is that the project is referencing own package built via `pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -v /app` and it has symbolic link to copied "src" directory and not the local files.
so whenever I make some changes to code and want to test it out, I have to rebuild the image and is slowing me down.

Is there any way to update project's package while referencing to local files? or only execute copying local files and build package when rebuilding?

Answer (score -1):

To achieve faster development cycles and avoid rebuilding the Docker image every time you make changes to your code, you can leverage Docker volumes to mount the local source code into the container. This way, the changes you make on the local files will be immediately reflected in the running container without the need for rebuilding.

Here's a version of your `docker-compose.yml` file that includes volume mounting:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  myproject:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    environment:
      - PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
      - PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - ./src:/app/src
    entrypoint: "python /app/src/generative_agents/main.py"
```

With this configuration, the local `src` directory will be mounted into the container at the same path (`/app/src`). Any changes you make in the local `src` directory will be immediately available to the containerized application.

Additionally, since you're using the `python:3.11` base image, you don't need to manually install dependencies using `pip` in your Dockerfile. The base image already includes Python, so you can remove the `RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -v /app` line from your Dockerfile.

Comment: This answer looks like ChatGPT